# Program always outputs 0 value

Tags: c, function

```
#include <stdio.h>
void volume()
{
   float pi=3.14,r,v;
   printf("\nEnter the radius: ");
   scanf("%f",&r);
   v=(1/3)*pi*r*r*r;
   printf("%f",v);
}
int main()
{
   volume();

}
```

This is C program to find volume using functions.
Compiler shows no error or warnings but the output is always zero.

Comment: Hint: compile with warnings at the highest level. The format specifier in `scanf` is invalid.

Comment: `(1/3)` is integer math which is 0.  change it to `(1.0 / 3.0)`

Comment: There's the reading of `float` and `1/3` is an `int` division. Use `pi*r*r*r/3` instead.

Comment: http://c-faq.com/expr/truncation1.html

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Because 1/3 is not 0.3333 in C, it is 0.

**Solution:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
void volume()
{
   float pi=3.14,r,v;
   printf("\nEnter the radius: ");
   scanf("%f",&r);
   v=(((float)1)/3)*pi*r*r*r;
   printf("%f",v);
}
int main()
{
   volume();

}
```

Comment: Why did you took (float), does it make a difference? and what is the use of it?

Comment: @Avi Read about type casting in your C textbook or tutorial.

Answer (score 4):

you have zero here due to `1/3` is integer division `= 0`

replace  `v=(1/3)*pi*r*r*r;` with  `v=(1.f/3.f)*pi*r*r*r;`

Answer (score 1):

That's because anything multiplied by `0` is `0`, and `1/3` is `0`.

`1/3` is `0` because both `1` and `3` are literals of type `int`, and dividing two integers results in an integer again.

Fix: `1.0/3.0` because `1.0` and `3.0` are floating point literals, so you get floating-point division.

Comment: Wouldn't it work if you just fixed the numerator or denominator only?  i.e. `1/3.0`?

Comment: @AndyJ Yes, then the other operand would be implicitly converted to `double`, but I prefer being explicit.

Answer (score 1):

It's due to the fact that `1 / 3` is done as integer division because both operands are type `int`<sup>(a)</sup>. So the final result is zero.

You can  get the intended effect simply by ensuring one of the operands is non-integer, such as with:

```
v = (1.0f / 3) * pi * r * r * r;
```

That will work, because it results in a float (inside the parentheses) of `0.333...`. However, there's absolutely *no* real reason why you need to parrot the equation shown in text books, you can achieve the same result with the simpler:

```
v = pi * r * r * r / 3;
```

Because all those variable are floating point, the result of the final `something / 3` is *also* done as floating point.

---

And, just some quick advice, you *may* want to consider using `double` types rather than `float`. The `float` type generally uses less space but, unless you have large arrays of them, it's not usually a problem. The `double` type gives a much greater range and precision.

---

In addition, `3.14` is not really *that* precise a value for `pi`. Most implementations will define an `M_PI` constant in `math.h` for you to use but it's not mandated by the standard. So, you can use something like this to get a more accurate value:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

// Define if implementation doesn't provide.

#ifndef M_PI
    #define M_PI 3.14159265358979323846
#endif

static void GetRadiusAndPrintVolume(void) {
    printf("\nEnter the radius: ");
    double radius;
    scanf("%lf", &radius);

    double volume = M_PI * radius * radius * radius / 3;

    printf("Volume for radius %f is %f\n", radius, volume);
}

int main() {
    GetRadiusAndPrintVolume();
}
```

---

And, finally, you *may* want to check that equation of yours. Though you don't say explicitly, it very much *looks* like it's supposed to be the volume of a sphere.

If that *is* the case, the formula should be `4/3 π r3` rather than `1/3`. Hence the statement would be:

```
double volume = M_PI * radius * radius * radius * 4 / 3;
```

---

<sup>(a)</sup> If you're interested, this is all covered by the "Usual arithmetic conversions" section of the C standard (section `6.3.1.8` in `C11`):

> Many operators that expect operands of arithmetic type cause conversions and yield result types in a similar way. The purpose is to determine a common real type for the operands and result.

It then goes on to list what happens for specific cases, which is generally that the "lesser" (in terms of its range and/or precision) operand is upgraded to the same type as the "greater" operand. That's the basic idea though, if you want the *full* picture, you should refer to the previously mentioned section.

In *your* specific case, since both operands of `1 / 3` are of type `int`, the calculation and the result is done as an `int`, meaning it truncates the fractional part (giving zero).

Comment: And if it hasn't been said, belated congrats on the 600K mark `:)` You Leffler and Dash have cornered the market...